# How is a jQuery reference saved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am messing with jQuery and JavaScript prototyping and made this tiny little thing to try and understand how jQ objects can be saved/accessed.

I made a single class that has a single property

```
var class1 = function(){
    this.div = $('<div class = "test"/>');
}
```

I then made a few prototype methods to manipulate it, like changing its colour and html values.

Then I made two instances of the class and was able to alter each instance's individual DOM element.

```
var myDiv1 = new class1().build().colour('green').colour('red');

var myDiv2 = new class1().build().colour('red').doHTML();
```

I was really surprised to see that each class maintained a reference to a different DOM element, even though it was already appended to the `<body>`. I am wondering how this is actually working. Are there hidden DOM ids that the class or jQuery is keeping a reference to? How does it know which DOM element to manipulate?

Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/o2uuevgx/3/

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery? It is more like how does JavaScript work.

Comment: Yep, as @epascarello mentioned, this is just maintaining a reference to an instance. Here's an example with just plain JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/tek86gbu/

Comment: Two instances == two different DOM elements. How could it be otherwise?

Comment: I thought it might treat it the same way as having to references of this.DOM = $('.myDiv') where changing this.DOM in either reference would change all divs of class 'myDiv'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript variables track objects by reference.

Because DOM nodes are objects, any changes to a variable that references a DOM node object will make changes directly to the object that is referenced.

A simple example:

```
// create an object
var x = {foo: "bar"};

// create a "reference" to that object
var ref = x;

// manipulate the reference variable
ref.foo = "hello";

// check the original object
console.log(x.foo);

//=> "hello"
```

This is no different if `this.div` is a reference to a DOM node (created by jQuery) and you do `this.div.css("color", "red")`; The underlying (referenced) object will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery keeps a reference to it. It makes a reference when you create the element and stores it internally.

Comment: So if I was planning on building a complex (positionally speaking, not # of DOM elements) DOM structure, it is safe to declare all my "building blocks" as JQ elements? Does this take up a lot of resources or pose some other threats? Example.. http://jsfiddle.net/f6qtb46v/